# Error in AWS Autoscaling configuration with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, autoscaling

I am trying to setup a autoscaling environment with AWS Autoscaling and Launch configuration.

Below is my tfvar for launch Configuration

```
config_name = "name"
image_id = "ami-test"
instance_type = "c4.large"
key_name = "EC2-key"
security_groups = ["sg-123456789",
    "sg-123456789099"]
associate_public_ip_address = false
enable_monitoring = true
ebs_optimized = true
root_size = 10
root_volume_type = "standard"
root_encrypted = true
device_name = "/dev/sdf"
ebs_volume = 30
ebs_delete = true
ebs_encrypted = true
ebs_volume_type = "gp2"
iam_instance_profile = "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:instance-profile/EC2ROLE"
```

This is creating a config without any issues and the config created from console and this tfvar execution is almost similar.

Below is the tfvars for autoscaling group.

```
scaling_name = "EC2-Scaling"
vpc_zone_identifier = ["subnet-123456789", "subnet-asdfghfjk"]
max_size = 2
min_size = 1
health_check_type = "ELB"
launch_configuration = "name"
termination_policies = ["NewestInstance",
    "OldestLaunchConfiguration"]
enabled_metrics = ["GroupInServiceCapacity",
    "GroupMaxSize",
    "GroupTotalCapacity",
    "GroupTotalInstances",
    "GroupMinSize"]
health_check_grace_period = 300
policy_name = "autoscaling_policy"
```

This is also appearing fine when checking in console. But when the scaling group tries to spin an instance up it is throwing error as below.

```
Launching a new EC2 instance: i-21358239842. Status Reason: Instance became unhealthy while waiting for instance to be in InService state. Termination Reason: Client.InternalError: Client error on launch
```

Pls point me to some errors in what I am doing or am I missing something.

As pointed in comment this is the resources class.

```
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "launch_configuration" {
  name = var.config_name
  image_id = var.image_id
  instance_type = var.instance_type
  key_name = var.key_name
  security_groups = var.security_groups
  associate_public_ip_address = var.associate_public_ip_address
  enable_monitoring = var.enable_monitoring
  ebs_optimized = var.ebs_optimized
  
  root_block_device {
    volume_size = var.root_size
    volume_type = var.root_volume_type
    encrypted = var.root_encrypted
  }
  
  ebs_block_device {
    device_name = var.device_name
    volume_size = var.ebs_volume
    delete_on_termination = var.ebs_delete
    encrypted = var.ebs_encrypted
    volume_type = var.ebs_volume_type
  }
  iam_instance_profile  = var.iam_instance_profile
}


resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "autoscaling" {
  name = var.scaling_name
  vpc_zone_identifier        = var.vpc_zone_identifier  
  max_size = var.max_size
  min_size = var.min_size
  health_check_type = var.health_check_type
  launch_configuration = var.launch_configuration
  termination_policies = var.termination_policies
  enabled_metrics = var.enabled_metrics
  
  instance_refresh {
    strategy = "Rolling"
  }
  
  health_check_grace_period = var.health_check_grace_period
  wait_for_capacity_timeout = 0 ##Skips waiting for capacity and proceeds to create a scaling group
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_policy" "dynamic_scaling" {
  name                   = var.policy_name
  adjustment_type        = "ChangeInCapacity"
  autoscaling_group_name = aws_autoscaling_group.autoscaling.name
  policy_type            = "TargetTrackingScaling"

  target_tracking_configuration {
    predefined_metric_specification {
      predefined_metric_type = "ASGAverageCPUUtilization"
    }
    target_value = 40.0
  }
}
```

Currently I am thinking of solving this in either of the two solutions.

As mentioned by @Arun K Setup the ALB with health check to forward requests to the autoscaling group or ring health check to this

Comment: so the ELB health check is failing, isn't it. whats the healthcheck configuration.

Comment: I have not created ELB as this was failing. Do you want me to check after I create the ELB?
I am planning on checking HTTPS on ELB on this auto scaling group

Comment: Yes please. and it would be great if you can post the stack template.

Comment: health_check_type = "ELB" means the autoscaling will use ELB's health check to determine whether the instances are healthy. But i am surprised that it allowed you to crate the autoscaling group with health check type as ELB without an ELB.

Comment: Showing tfvars without showing the actual terraform code that uses those vars is kind of useless.

Comment: Added the resources classes in the question working on ALB now will post if that works out @Arun

Comment: Also Since I am skipping wait for capacity step in Autoscaling resource it is allowing me to create the resource even if the capacity is not able to be achieved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits to @Arunk Who pointed the Error in the configuration of autoscaling group.

The main cause of error was

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "autoscaling" {
..
health_check_type = "ELB"
..
```

I had specified that the Health check was done in Elastic load balancer but I had not assigned the autscaling group to an Load balancer . All I had to do was Create the complete stack below.

```
resource "aws_lb" "example" {
  load_balancer_type = "gateway"
  name               = "example"

  subnet_mapping {
    subnet_id = aws_subnet.example.id
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "example" {
  name     = "example"
  port     = 6081
  protocol = "GENEVE"
  vpc_id   = aws_vpc.example.id

  health_check {
    port     = 80
    protocol = "HTTP"
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "example" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.example.id

  default_action {
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.example.id
    type             = "forward"
  }
}
resource "aws_autoscaling_attachment" "asg_attachment_bar" {
  autoscaling_group_name = aws_autoscaling_group.asg.id
  alb_target_group_arn   = aws_alb_target_group.test.arn
}
```

Note: Code copied from terraform site.

Once this setup was put in place the error I was getting got resolved.

Answer (score 1):

From the terraform manual for aws_autoscaling_group:

> wait_for_capacity_timeout (Default: "10m") A maximum duration that
> Terraform should wait for ASG instances to be healthy before timing
> out. (See also Waiting for Capacity below.) Setting this to "0" causes
> Terraform to skip all Capacity Waiting behavior.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/autoscaling_group

I think its unhealthy on the basis that it cant communicate *yet*, judging from the ec2 error. 0 seconds is too short a time for an ec2 instance to go from initialising to inService, the check of which will take place after the "aws_autoscaling_group" resource is fired in terraform. If I were a web user (or health check) hitting the ec2 instance thats currently initialising, I'd get a 500, not a 500-but-ec2-will-be-span-up-soon-try-again-in-a-minute. In `resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "autoscaling"`, try giving it a value:

```
wait_for_capacity_timeout = 300
```

I've set it on the basis of your other value:

```
health_check_grace_period = 300
```

So this value means it will wait 300 seconds after ec2 instances have signalled in service before doing a health check.